# series of an arbitrary sequence multiplying 1/n

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, sequences-and-series, complex-analysis, analysis

Let $(r_n)_{n=1}^\infty$ be an arbitrary sequence of numbers in $[0,1]$. The series $\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{1}{n^2\sqrt{|x-r_n|}}$ converges for almost all $x$ in $[0,1]$. Is it true or not true?

I want to give a counterexample. My idea is to consider the collection of all rational numbers in $[0,1]$. If I put them in the order $0,1, 1/2, 1/3,2/3,1/4/3/4,\cdots$, I can only obtain $|x-r_{\frac{n(n+1)}{2}}|<\frac{1}{n}$. But this cannot deduce that the series diverges...

How to solve?

Comment: What is the series? You just have $\sum_{n=1}^\infty$

Comment: Is it $\frac{1}{n}$ or $\frac{1}{n^2}$ ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The family of functions $f_n \colon x\mapsto \frac{1}{\sqrt{\lvert x- r_n\rvert}}$ is bounded in $L^1([0,1])$,

$$\lVert f_n\rVert_{L^1} = \int_0^1 \frac{dx}{\sqrt{\lvert x-r_n\rvert}} \leqslant \int_0^1 \frac{1}{\sqrt{\left\lvert x-\frac{1}{2}\right\rvert}} = 2\int_0^{1/2}x^{-1/2}\,dx = \left[4\sqrt{x}\right]_0^{1/2} = 2\sqrt{2}.$$

Therefore the series $$\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{n^2} f_n$$

is convergent in $L^1([0,1])$, and since all functions are non-negative, the series converges almost everywhere.